# Modifying the LocateWidget.mxml Locate and Clear functions

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, flex, arcgis-flex-viewer

I am using Robert's [compiled TOC](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=e2cb71d5c04d40d19e9f945ae0db7ce8) widget and attempting to modify the LocateWidget.mxml for the flexviewer. The workflow I have in mind is that user performs an address search clicks the locate button and all my defined operational layers turn on. The clear button would then turn them off.

My attempt at the code is posted here:
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/57851-Modifying-the-LocateWidget.mxml-Locate-and-Clear-functions

Comment: code posted on ESRI Forum http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/58008-Modifying-the-LocateWidget.mxml-Locate-and-Clear-functions?p=199737#post199737

Answer (score 1):

You need to check in the ActionScript code block for scale change, as soon as this takes place you need to check if the scale is larger then 18056 scale, turn on the OP Layers otherwise keep default.

If you could post your MXML file it will be of more help to assist you in this.